# Built a 2 meter 5 element Yagi

Tags: antenna-construction, dipole, yagi

Straight dipoles. I can't get the Yagi to tune.  I have tried the 4:1 Balun method with coax but not able to tune.  With the straight unbalanced input to the dipole I get a 1:1 swr on about 129 MHz Suggestions? Shall I shorten the dipole?

Comment: Welcome to ham.se! A photo of the antenna in it's testing configuration might be useful here...in my experience Yagi antennas are sensitive to odd* details like proximity to ground and feedpoint terminations, among other things.

Comment: Also please include the plans you're working from.

Comment: Please add more details to allow us to understand what we’re dealing with here